# How can I speed up elpy

Tags: elpy

I’m using elpy for python development in emacs.

Some of the features are indispensable, like ‘C-c C-t’ for running individual tests.

However, after maybe an hour of development, my session is very slow—-like 1 full second command between keystrokes as simple as ‘C-n’, which becomes unusable.

I suspect I have something misconfigured or have conflicting autocomplete libraries, etc.

My question is: how can I (a) diagnose what is causing so much slowness and (b) fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the memory footprint of Emacs when you start, versus the memory footprint of when Emacs slows down?  E.g., on OSX 10.6.8 there is an Activity Monitor that shows the memory usage ...  Also, check what subprocesses (if any) are running through Emacs when you experience the slow down ...